# Rendered image doesn't show what Rendered Viewport shows... (pictures below)

Tags: rendering, camera, tracking, bezier-curves

It's kind of an interesting result.

Here is how render viewport should look on frame 1:

[image]

Here is what happens when I press **F12**:

[image]

It's like I have a second camera (although I don't) somewhere below. What is even weirder is that If I place the camera **behind** the wall...

[image]

it shows everything correctly (example cube is seen):

[image]

As you can see, my camera is following an object that is on Bezier curve WHILE being on Bezier curve (right) itself. This animation is working perfectly on rendered viewport but not if I use ctrl+F12. Just the same grey viewpoint.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have a compositing node setup? Also, [upload your file here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Nodes are there. Blend is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a plane in front of your objects and the camera:

[image]

Which is not visible in the file because it was hidden:

[image]

You could either delete the Plane object or hide it from the camera render (Check the camera icon).

Comment: If this answered your question, press the check mark next to my answer to mark this question resolved.